# Getting CORS error when using variable in api call

Tags: vue.js, axios

Good day.

When i do the following api call with axios it works just fine but when i try to use a variable in said api call i get a cors error. What am i doing wrong?

When i use it without a variable, this works just fine:

```
somecall({state}){
  axiosB
  .get("/lmao/10.0.0.190")
  .then(res =>
    state.response = res.data);
    console.log(state.response)
}
```

When i use a variable to perform the api call, this gives me a CORS error:

```
somecall({state, ip}){
  axiosB
  .get("/lmao/", ip)
  .then(res =>
    state.response = res.data);
    console.log(state.response)
}
```

The value i am trying to pass is 10.0.0.190 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Vuex (are you?), the syntax should be:

```
somecall({state}, ip){
  axiosB
  .get("/lmao/" + ip)
  .then(res =>
    state.response = res.data);
    console.log(state.response)
}
```

Note that the payload comes as a second argument after the deconstructed context, rather than together with it.

Or the problem may be with this line:

```
.get("/lmao/", ip)
```

and may need to be changed as above.

Comment: Thanks. i was using a "," instead of +.
Ill be able to accept your answer in 4 minutes